# How can I add a delay before it continues

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way in the normal obj-c or cocos2d to make a delay inside a `if-else` block?
Like

```
if ([self isValidTileCoord:cTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:cTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle0];
    //wait two seconds
    //perform another task
}
```

Just a simple lag to wait between two tasks, or stalling an action. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` method to delay tasks:

```
if ([self isValidTileCoord:cTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:cTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle0];
    //wait two seconds
    [self performSelector:@selector(continueTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

}
```

And in the selector method:

```
-(void)continueTask
{
    //perform another task
}
```

Comment: I would like it to perform inside the same method though

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference, so if you want to do that for layout reasons, I can understand, but the code is very simple and not too hard to follow.

Comment: If you don't like this method of delaying actions, give creker's answer a try. If you do this, I would recommend looking at Apple's documentation on dispatch_get_current_queue(): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_get_current_queue.3.html

Comment: One thing more, that if the app is in the background then still it will count the time. While cocos2d schedular is paused during app in background.

Comment: The function will queue the selector on the threads run loop, so I think it does run in the background (I am not sure though). If you want to cancel a previous `performSelector: withObject: after delay:` message then you can use `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. I would use GCD

```
if ([self isValidTileCoord:cTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:cTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle0];
    //wait two seconds
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        //perform another task;
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `dispatch_get_current_queue()` anymore. It's deprecated and not completely safe. If you need to be specific about the queue, it should be passed, or it should be defined as happening on a non-specific queue or the main queue.

Comment: This worked, but as @JasonCoco states is deprecated I'll go with user####### instead.

Comment: Only `dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated. Everything else is still valid. Like @JasonCoco said, just pass any other queue instead of `dispatch_get_current_queue`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the cocos2d you can also run an Action on the node like,

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(anothertaks)],nil]];
```

Perform selector will also work but the problem is that all the schedulers of cocos2D get paused when the app go to background but on the other side perform selector will still count the time, so some time it create task,animation,etc syncing problems.

Perform selector:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(continueTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```